# ddrescue not starting after cancelling

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, data-loss, data-corruption, ddrescue

I used ddrescue to copy data from an about-to-fail hard drive to another clean drive. I had formatted the targetted drive and began the process successfully but later canceled it because I had to get out of the workplace.

Long story short, I reformatted the target disk again and renamed, moved the rescue.map to Trash file, restored it, and renamed it to the original name again, all in an attempt to force the process to start fresh. It was wrong indeed, but I didn't know at the time. 
Tried to run this command `sudo ddrescue --force -n /dev/sdb /dev/sdc rescue.map` again but now it doesn't give any sign of starting the process let alone of progress.

What should I do?

Comment: I see no OS/product/release mentioned, and thus see nothing yet on-topic for this site. Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic